# Add attribute with renderer using a directive

Tags: angular

I want to achieve extending an HTML tag with an attribute but encapsulate this with an angular 2 component.

Let's assume the original markup using my Angular 2 component foo

```
<div foo="x"></div>
```

The foo attribute should transform the div like:

```
<div some-other-fancy-attribute="x"></div>
```

First I tried implementing a directive but I could not figure out how to add another attribute to the hosting element using Renderer from angular/core.

Then I read about Angular 2 components using an attribute selector like [foo]. I liked the idea of using a template to render some-other-fancy-attribute.

However, the template get's rendered AFTER the tag so I end up with:

```
<div foo="x">some-other-fancy-attribute="x"
```

Isn't there an easy way to encapsulate some attribute creation?
Thought this is a trivial one but it gives me more headache than expected.

Comment: Excellent question. I have text resources wrapped in a custom tag and with the solutions below, I can know what the resource key is!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If I understood you right..
your idea is good, should work!

See this plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/YctUpK9r9AqIk0D1qvgZ?p=preview

**EDIT: updated to use Renderer2**

```js
import {Component, Directive, NgModule, ElementRef, Renderer2, ViewChild} from '@angular/core'
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser'

@Directive({
  selector: '[foo]'
})
export class MyFancyDirective {

  constructor (private _elRef: ElementRef, private _renderer: Renderer2) { console.log('!'); }

  ngOnInit() {
    this._renderer.setAttribute(this._elRef.nativeElement, 'another-fancy-attribute', 'HERE I AM !!');
  }

}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2 #header foo (click)="headerClicked()">Hello {{name}}</h2>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {

  @ViewChild('header', { static: true }) header: ElementRef;

  name:string;
  constructor() {
    this.name = 'Angular2'
  }

  headerClicked() {
    console.dir(this.header.nativeElement.attributes['another-fancy-attribute'].value);
  }
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ App, MyFancyDirective ],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: That's it, I missed the setElementAttribute method. :) Thank you.

Comment: `Renderer` is deprecated, should use `Renderer2` and just change `setElementAttribute` to be `setAttribute` ..

Answer (score 21):

We can use **setAttribute** method of **Renderer2** class

```js
import {Directive, ElementRef, Renderer2, Input, HostListener, OnInit} from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[DirectiveName]'
})
export class DirectiveNameDirective implements OnInit {
 constructor(public renderer : Renderer2,public hostElement: ElementRef){}
ngOnInit() {
      this.renderer.setAttribute(this.hostElement.nativeElement, "data-name", "testname");
      }
    }
```

Comment: using your code as a reference, i did this `this._renderer.setAttribute(this._elRef.nativeElement, 'fxFlex', '30');` and in the rendered DOM content i observed the camelCase of fxFlex turned to lower case. ?Still stuck