# Angular2 insert custom attribute in tag with directive

Tags: angular, attributes, tags, element, directive

I have an angular 2 project and I'm using PrimeNG.
I'm using a special tag with a lot of custom attributes and these attributes are always the same for this tag.
I want to externalize these attributes and I created a custom directive used to add all attributes I need.
The problem is that some of these attributes aren't native and maybe they aren't recognized. I get the error "Failed to execute 'setAttribute' on 'Element': '[myCustomAttribute]' is not a valid attribute name.

This is my directive:

```js
@Directive({
  selector: '[def-calendar]'
})
export class DefaultCalendarDirective {

  constructor(private _elRef: ElementRef, private _renderer: Renderer2) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this._renderer.setAttribute(this._elRef.nativeElement, '[yearRange]', '1900:2100');
  }
}
```

Anyone know how can I fix it? 
I don't know if is there a way to copy the element such as string and manipulate the string adding my attributes.

Thanks
Fabrizio

Answer (score 2):

This might be useful for you. 
[Angular2 add attribute with Renderer using a directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39664066/angular2-add-attribute-with-renderer-using-a-directive).

I think the square bracket between the yearRange is the culprit. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `renderer.setAttribute(...)` to set attributes that don't belong to the native HTML element you're using.
`yearRange` isn't even an attribute to be accurate for any native HTML element. It should be declared as an input in class of the directive in order to set values for it properly:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[def-calendar]'
})
export class DefaultCalendarDirective implements OnInit {

  @Input() yearRange: string = '1900:2100';

  constructor() {
  }

  public ngOnInit() {}
}
```

You can also change the input value by passing it a string (or you can also use binding instead) when you're using the directive on an element.

```
<someElement def-calendar yearRange="1900:2100"></someElement>
```

Comment: Hi and thanks for reply. So I don't need to set the value, I need to manipulate the tag adding some attributes.
Let me explain:
I have this
**<p-calendar def-calendar [(ngModel)]="clientFilter.dateEnd" dateFormat="></p-calendar>**
and I want to have this:
**<p-calendar def-calendar [(ngModel)]="clientFilter.dateEnd" dateFormat=" [monthNavigator]="true" [yearNavigator]="true" yearRange="2000:2030"></p-calendar>**

Comment: You can't "add" attributes. Either you use inputs or you use the default attributes of the element you're adding the directive to (disabled or value in case of button for example).

Comment: And based on what you wrote, you need to define the inputs `dateFormat`, `monthNavigator`, and `yearRange` in your directive's class to make it work. I don't see any other way for doing this.

Comment: Ok this is a bad thing.. I was looking for a way to manipulate the tag instead add attributes, I don't want to add inputs on tag, my target is to clean the code

Comment: I don't see why you have a problem using inputs. It's the only way to "add custom attributes" to the component/directive you're creating. If you don't exactly know what an input is, have a look at the [input doc of Angular](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction). It should help you.

Comment: I know what's an input, i want to clear my code and I want to centralize the common code and avoid to write the same things everywhere. I tried to create a component but I lost the form validation control

Answer (score 0):

We can use **setAttribute** method of **Renderer2** class

```js
import {Directive, ElementRef, Renderer2, Input, HostListener} from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[DirectiveName]'
})
export class DirectiveNameDirective {
 constructor(public renderer : Renderer2,public hostElement: ElementRef){}
ngOnInit() {
      this.renderer.setAttribute(this.hostElement.nativeElement, "data-name", "testname");
      }
    }
```

Comment: Hi, I tried your solution but I get this error:
**"Failed to execute 'setAttribute' on 'Element': 'data- name' is not a valid attribute name."**

Comment: Hi @FabrizioP There is space between data- name, please remove space and check, I will change my answer.

Comment: Hi and thanks, if I set data-name it works but I need to add ***ngIf** and this not works

Comment: Hi You can directly use *ngIf to element, Using directive we can set data attribute

Comment: Of course, I can.. But to keep the code clean I want to create a directive accepting a value and make some checks on directive to show or hide the element.